# Angular 2 dynamic forms example with ngmodel results in "expression has changed after it was checked"

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm looking to use this [example](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html) provided in the Angular documentation to leverage Dynamic forms in combination with the [(ngmodel)]. so that dynamic form controls can be bound to an model.

However, when I try to bind a control to [(ngMode)], I see the error message

> Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/3hpld2nUTIVgzhHbscaY?p=preview) is an sample Plunker with the changes made.

I modified the QuestionBase class to hold a key

```
export class QuestionBase<T>{
      ...
      modelKey:string;
      ...
}
```

Within the QuestionService, each question now has the name of the model it should update

```
  new TextboxQuestion({
          ...
          modelKey: 'firstName'
  }),
```

In the DynamicFormQuestionComponent the model is passed in as an input varialbe

```
  export class DynamicFormQuestionComponent {
        ...
        @Input() model: SampleModel;
        ...
  }
```

The DynamicFormQuestionComponent HTML fields have been modified to use [(ngModel)]

```
<input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="question.key"
        [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type" [(ngModel)]="model[question.modelKey]">
```

Here the control should be bound to the the resolved 'model[question.modelKey]'

Given that I don't see [(ngModel)] used in the example provided in the official documentation.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: two-way-bound ngModel is meant for template driven forms rather than the dynamic reactive forms

Comment: Sorry wasn't able to wade through the plunkr.. 
But The following two resources will be useful to help you contrast how to do things the template driven vs the reactive way:

* [Angular 2 Forms Video | Kara Erickson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYv9lsrV0s4), 
* [Angular 2 Forms Repo | Kara Erickson](https://github.com/kara/ac-forms), 
* [NgModel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html), 
* [FormControl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I didn't realized you couldn't mix the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad you found it helpful.. I'll just leave this here for others in future..

> Two-way-bound `ngModel` is designed for template driven forms rather
>   than the dynamic reactive forms.
>
> The following resources will be useful to help you contrast how to do
>   things the "template driven" way vs the "dynamic reactive" way:
>
> - [Angular 2 Forms Video | Kara Erickson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYv9lsrV0s4)
> - [Angular 2 Forms Repo | Kara Erickson](https://github.com/kara/ac-forms)
> - [NgModel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html)
> - [FormControl](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `ngModel` then you also need to set the name on that control:

i.e. `[(ngModel)]="model[question.modelKey]" [name]="question.key"`

I tried this in your sample plunkr, and it allows binding back to the model .. but now throws some other errors on the binding `*ngIf` to `isValid`.

In short, it looks like you *can* mix the two .. but then you have `ngModel` and `FormGroup.value` both capturing the same data which is quite confusing.

I haven't found the need to try to mix these, if you're using a dynamic form let it do the work and then get the values when you need them (on save/submit). You might be asking for trouble if you try to mix them