# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError Explained

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, angular2-databinding

Please explain to me why I keep getting this error: `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.`

Obviously, I only get it in dev mode, it doesn't happen on my production build, but it's very annoying and I simply don't understand the benefits of having an error in my dev environment that won't show up on prod --probably because of my lack of understanding.

Usually, the fix is easy enough, I just wrap the error causing code in a setTimeout like this:

```typescript
setTimeout(()=> {
    this.isLoading = true;
}, 0);
```

Or force detect changes with a constructor like this: `constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}`:

```typescript
this.isLoading = true;
this.cd.detectChanges();
```

But why do I constantly run into this error? I want to understand it so I can avoid these hacky fixes in the future.

Comment: [Everything you need to know about the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) explains this behavior in great details

Comment: I also face the same issue, it only happens on DEV and only affecting my console logs. Instead of introducing any new code to the project, I simply hide/block this error from the console.

Comment: Official guideline from Angular - https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

Comment: The solution you mentioned is not a hacky but a proper solution. It is described here: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O47uUnJjbJc. Please have a look on the YouTube video to get a quick overview and possible solutions

Comment: I've got a really nasty case where nothing helps me to avoid this error: `[class.highlight-row]="isContainerRowHighlighted(row.id)"` for `CdkRow` row in the Material grid...

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't tell you what expression changed. It just shows you the values which may or may not be helpful.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

A lot of understanding came once I understood [the Angular Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) and their relationship with change detection.

I was trying to get Angular to update a global flag bound to the `*ngIf` of an element, and I was trying to change that flag inside of the `ngOnInit()` life cycle hook of another component.

According to the documentation, this method is called after Angular has already detected changes:

> Called once, after the first ngOnChanges().

So updating the flag inside of `ngOnChanges()` won't initiate change detection. Then, once change detection has naturally triggered again, the flag's value has changed and the error is thrown.

In my case, I changed this:

```
constructor(private globalEventsService: GlobalEventsService) {

}

ngOnInit() {
    this.globalEventsService.showCheckoutHeader = true;
}
```

To this:

```
constructor(private globalEventsService: GlobalEventsService) {
    this.globalEventsService.showCheckoutHeader = true;
}

ngOnInit() {

}
```

and it fixed the problem :)

Comment: My problem was similar. That I did a mistake after long hours, and defined a variable outside the ngOnInit function and constructor. This receives data changes from an observable, which is placed in the initalization function. Did the same thing as you to fix the error.

Comment: Very similar all around, but I was trying to scroll (`router.navigate`) upon load to a fragment if present in the URL. This code was initially placed in `AfterViewInit` where I was receving the error, then I moved as you say to the constructor but it wasn't respecting the fragment. Moving to `ngOnInit` resolved :) thanks!

Comment: What if my html is bound to a getter returning time as "HH:MM" via get ClockValue() { return DateTime.TimeAMPM(new Date()) } it will eventually trip when the minutes change while detection is running, how can I fix this?

Comment: Same here. Also found that wrapping into `setInterval()` works also if it needs to fire after other lifetime event code.

Comment: Got a very similar scenario, although my changed state was not a boolean flag but some enum (status) field. The fix was to wrap html referencing this problematic status field with "ngIf" which will check some other field already initialized.

Comment: comparing 2way binding in angular vs wpf is very interest for me! a lot of painful complexity in angular only for 2way binding at a browser app!! shouldn't web client be simpler that native app client?!!

Answer (score 229):

I had a similar issue. Looking at the [lifecycle hooks documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks), I changed `ngAfterViewInit` to `ngAfterContentInit` and it worked.

Comment: @PhilipEnc my issue was related to a change triggered by the DOM changing. When the DOM would change, the QueryList object (that came from a @ContentChildren property) would update, and inside the method that the update called it changed the two-way bound property. This created the problem I was having. Wrapping that change to the two-property with `setTimeout` like you show above did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: In my case I had placed some code that changed the value of primeng grid array in ngAfterContentInit , I placed the code in ngOnInit and it worked.

Comment: `ngAfterContentChecked` works here while `ngAfterContentInit` still throws error.

Comment: ngAfterContentChecked use but project loaded very slow

Comment: If we try to change the binded prop of ngIf before ngAfterViewInit then it wont throw error. i.e. we can set the value inside constructor, ngOnChanges, ngOninit without any error.

Comment: Caution (from comments) `ngAfterContentChecked` (and `ngAfterViewChecked`) is triggered on every Angular check. It can be fired multiple times every second. So be careful. By [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) `ngAfterViewInit` is called once after first `ngAfterContentChecked`. I wouldn't use the `Checked` methods for init. It's a bad workaround. The perfect solution depends on the individual case. You maybe using Angular incorrectly and need to rethink the implementation. Angular can be very challenging and exhausting. But don't copy (or upvote) code you don't understand. :)

Answer (score 162):

This error indicates a real problem in your application, therefore it makes sense to throw an exception.

In `devMode` change detection adds an additional turn after every regular change detection run to check if the model has changed.

If the model has changed between the regular and the additional change detection turn, this indicates that either

- change detection itself has caused a change
- a method or getter returns a different value every time it is called

which are both bad, because it is not clear how to proceed because the model might never stabilize.

If Angular runs change detection until the model stabilizes, it might run forever.
If Angular doesn't run change detection, then the view might not reflect the current state of the model.

See also [What is difference between production and development mode in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34868810/what-is-difference-between-production-and-development-mode-in-angular2/34868896#34868896)

Comment: How can I avoid seeing this error in the future? Is there a different way I need to be thinking about my code to ensure I do not make the same mistakes?

Comment: Usually this is caused by some lifecycle callbacks like `ngOnInit` or `ngOnChanges` to modify the model (some lifecycle callbacks allow modify the model others don't, I don't remember myself exactly which one do or do not). Don't bind to methods or functions in the view, instead bind to fields and update the fields in event handlers. If you must bind to methods, ensure that they always return the same value instance as long as there wasn't actually a change. Change detection will call these methods a lot.

Comment: For anyone arriving here who gets this error using ngx-toaster library, here is the bug report: https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr/issues/160

Comment: In my case I modified the model **inside a Typescript 'getter'**; notice how I `enable()` inside the getter:, `get isUseMode() { if (this._isUseMode) { this.formGroup.enable() } }` I moved `enable()` to the setter, and it works!

Comment: It's not necessarily a problem with the app. The fact that calling `changeRef.detectChanges()` is a solution / suppresses the error, is proof of this. It's like modifying state inside `$scope.$watch()` in Angular 1.

Comment: I don't know Angular 1 too well but change detection in Angular 2 works quite differently. Your are right that it is not necessarily a problem, but usually `cdRef.detectChanges()` is only necessary in some weird edge-cases and you should looks carefully when you need it that you understand properly why.

Comment: What if my html is bound to a getter returning time as "HH:MM" via 
`get ClockValue() { return DateTime.TimeAMPM(new Date()) }`  it will eventually trip when the minutes change while detection is running, how can I fix this?

Comment: That's a bad idea. Better to use interval or timer https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval and bind to it using `async`

Comment: That's a bad idea. Better to use interval or timer https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval and bind to it using `async`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I disagree with your statement "a real problem in your application". More often than not, it's just a poor design of Angular. When Angular developers realized that the mechanism they developed has holes - rather than redesigning it, they patched with this double check and exception. It's a fact that in many other frameworks developers can naturally write and put together components without coming across these counterintuitive and counterproductive issues, over-complication and exceptions. I believe Angular's parent-child model is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @rapt just don't use the default change detection strategy. The first mistake was that they added it at all, the 2nd that they made it the default. The 3rd, that all examples assume it is used. This is all just for easy onboarding of beginners. If you configure a linter rule that enforces OnPush everywhere and you use for example NgRx with `| async` pipe everywhere, you will hardly find a situation where you stumble upon this error and everything will be super fast.

Answer (score 132):

Angular runs change detection and when it finds that some values which has been passed to the child component have been changed, Angular throws the following error:

`ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` [click for more](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

In order to correct this we can use the `AfterContentChecked` life cycle hook and

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, AfterContentChecked} from '@angular/core';

  constructor(
  private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {

    this.cdref.detectChanges();

  }
```

Comment: Although this might fix the issue, isn't this very expansive and overkilling the CD?

Comment: I think this is the only answer that addresses this error being caused by passing value(s) to a child.  Thanks!

Comment: @Nicky Yes. Every time you touch on screen, anywhere, ngAfterContentChecked() is called

Comment: This solution helped me to solve my problem of passing back the change to app.components.ts from a child component. Thank you

Comment: do we do this in the child or parent component?  just hit this same issue and trying better to understand the root problem.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. I was using valueChanges on reactive forns in my ngOnit and applying your solution worked for me like a charm.

Comment: As @Nicky said, this should not be the answer, you can simply add console.log inside of ngAfterContentCheck() and see how expansive it is. This is simply working solution because detectChanges() has been called a lot.

Answer (score 80):

I'm using **ng2-carouselamos** (Angular 8 and Bootstrap 4)

Taking these steps fixed my problem:

1. Implement `AfterViewChecked`
2. Add `constructor(private changeDetector : ChangeDetectorRef ) {}`
3. Then `ngAfterViewChecked(){ this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); }`

Comment: that's gotta be demanding in terms of processing effort - sounds like this could be a real potential for a serious slow down in an app that needs speed

Comment: issue appear with me in angular 16 after i convert the project to single component mode but this solution fix my issue , Thank you

Comment: Sick and tired of seeing these low-effort answers that just nuke your application's performance to solve a tiny problem.

Answer (score 47):

**Update**

I highly recommend starting with [the OP's self response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48216423/777285) first: properly think about what can be done in the `constructor` vs what should be done in `ngOnChanges()`.

**Original**

This is more a side note than an answer, but it might help someone. I stumbled upon this problem when trying to make the presence of a button depend on the state of the form:

```html
<button *ngIf="form.pristine">Yo</button>
```

As far as I know, this syntax leads to the button being added and removed from the DOM based on the condition. Which in turn leads to the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

The fix in my case (although I don't claim to grasp the full implications of the difference), was to use `display: none` instead:

```html
<button [style.display]="form.pristine ? 'inline' : 'none'">Yo</button>
```

Comment: My understanding of the difference between the ngIf vs. the style is that the ngIf does not include the HTML in the page until the condition is true, thus reducing the "page weight" a tiny bit while the style technique causes the HTML to always be in the page and is simply hidden or shown based on the value of form.pristine.

Comment: You might as well use `[hidden]` instead of the very verbose `[style.display]` part. :)

Comment: Why not. Although, as mentioned by @Simon_Weaver in another comment on this page, `[hidden]` [will not always have the same behavior](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/dont-use-hidden-attribute-angularjs-2/) as `display: none`

Comment: I was showing two different buttons (logout/ login) with *ngIf in each button and this was causing the problem.

Comment: constructor was the right place for me, launching a material snack-bar

Answer (score 46):

Follow the below steps:

1.
Use 'ChangeDetectorRef' by importing it from @angular/core as follows:

```
import{ ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

2.
Implement it in constructor() as follows:

```
constructor(   private cdRef : ChangeDetectorRef  ) {}
```

3.
Add the following method to your function which you are calling on an event like click of button. So it look like this:

```
functionName() {   
    yourCode;  
    //add this line to get rid of the error  
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();     
}
```

Answer (score 46):

There were interesting answers but I didn't seem to find one to match my needs, the closest being from @chittrang-mishra which refers only to one specific function and not several toggles as in my app.

I did not want to use `[hidden]` to take advantage of `*ngIf` not even being a part of the DOM so I found the following solution which may not be the best for all as it suppresses the error instead of correcting it, but in my case where I know the final result is correct, it seems ok for my app.

What I did was implement `AfterViewChecked`, add `constructor(private changeDetector : ChangeDetectorRef  ) {}` and then

```
ngAfterViewChecked(){
  this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```

I hope this helps other as many others have helped me.

Comment: won't this trigger an infinite change detection loop? i mean, you are detecting for changes after you checked.

Comment: @ManuelAzar Apparently it does not. This is the ONLY solution that worked for me. AT LAST a bit of silence in my console. I was so tired of all these irrelevant change detection "errors".

Comment: What do you mean by suppressing the error? Isn't the change detected by the changeDetector?

Comment: @ManuelAzar There is no infinite loop because `ngAfterViewChecked` is only called once during the component lifecycle. Triggering a change detection cycle does NOT start the component lifecycle over again, so `ngAfterViewChecked` is not called a second time unless the component is re-rendered from scratch. (Note that some of the other hooks, such as `ngDoCheck`, WILL be triggered by extra change detection cycles because they misleadingly hook into the change detection cycle and NOT the component lifecycle directly. Using `detectChanges()` in a `ngDoCheck` will cause an infinite loop.)

Answer (score 32):

I was facing the same problem as value was changing in one of the array in my component. But instead of detecting the changes on value change, I changed the component change detection strategy to `onPush` (which will detect changes on object change and not on value change).

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
    selector: -
    ......
})
```

Comment: This seemed to work for adding/removing from controls dynamically.. are there any drawbacks?

Comment: Works like a charm in the situation I have at hand, thanks! A component was bound to a "global" object which was changed elsewhere and caused the Error to happen. This component already had an update handler for when the bound object was updated, this event handler now calls changeDetectorRef.detectChanges() in combination with the ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush this works as desired without the error.

Comment: @RicardoSaracino did you find any drawbacks?  I was wondering the same thing.  I know how change detection OnPush works, but wondering if there is a gotcha that maybe I'm missing.  I don't want to have to circle back.

Comment: @RicardoSaracino , Yes it has some drawbacks , you can refer this detailed link https://blog.angular-university.io/onpush-change-detection-how-it-works/

Comment: @BernoulliIT Thanks , I am glad that it worked for you.

Comment: Worked for me where loading ViewChild objects the first time was triggering this exception. It seems it checked the first time BEFORE assigning the object from a child, then detecting the first load as a change.

Now works like a charm with Angular 14, using Angular Material elements.

Answer (score 29):

In my case, I had this problem in my spec file, while running my tests.

I had to change `ngIf` **to** `[hidden]`

```html
<app-loading *ngIf="isLoading"></app-loading>
```

**to**

```html
<app-loading [hidden]="!isLoading"></app-loading>
```

Comment: About `[hidden]` : http://www.talkingdotnet.com/dont-use-hidden-attribute-angularjs-2/

Comment: The difference here is that `*ngIf` changes the DOM, adding and removing the element from the page, while `[hidden]` changes the visibility of the item while not removing it from the DOM.

Comment: But, this didn't really fix the real problem...?

Comment: This triggered all of my validators the moment one of these hidden fields changes, not a pretty site to see everything in red!

Answer (score 24):

Referring to the article https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

So the mechanics behind change detection actually works in a way that both change detection and verification digests are performed synchronously. That means, if we update properties asynchronously the values will not be updated when the verification loop is running and we will not get `ExpressionChanged...` error. The reason we get this error is, during the verification process, Angular sees different values then what it recorded during change detection phase. So to avoid that....

1) Use changeDetectorRef

2) use setTimeOut.  This will execute your code in another VM as a macro-task. Angular will not see these changes during verification process and you will not get that error.

```
 setTimeout(() => {
        this.isLoading = true;
    });
```

3) If you really want to execute your code on same VM use like

```
Promise.resolve(null).then(() => this.isLoading = true);
```

This will create a micro-task. The micro-task queue is processed after the current synchronous code has finished executing hence the update to the property will happen after the verification step.

Comment: Can you use option #3 with a style expression? I have a style expression for height that should be evaluated last, because it is based on injected content.

Comment: Sorry just saw your comment, yea i dont see any reason why not. So that should work with style changes as well.

Answer (score 13):

Tried most of the solutions suggested above. Only this worked for me in this scenario. I was using *ngIf to toggle angular material's indeterminate progressive bar based on api calls and it was throwing `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

In the component in question:

```
constructor(
    private ngZone: NgZone,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
        this.appService.appLoader$.subscribe(value => {
            this.loading = value;
            this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        });
    });
}
```

The trick is to bypass angular component's change detection using ngzone.

PS: Not sure if this is an elegant solution but using AfterContentChecked and AfterViewChecked lifecycle hook is bound to raise performance issues as your application gets bigger as it is triggered numerous times.

Comment: Stumbled upon the issue dealing with the same use case. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 12):

#### `@HostBinding` can be a confusing source of this error.

For example, lets say you have the following host binding in a component

```
// image-carousel.component.ts
@HostBinding('style.background') 
style_groupBG: string;
```

For simplicity, lets say this property is updated via the following input property:

```
@Input('carouselConfig')
public set carouselConfig(carouselConfig: string) 
{
    this.style_groupBG = carouselConfig.bgColor;   
}
```

In the parent component you are programatically setting it in `ngAfterViewInit`

```
@ViewChild(ImageCarousel) carousel: ImageCarousel;

ngAfterViewInit()
{
    this.carousel.carouselConfig = { bgColor: 'red' };
}
```

Here's what happens :

- Your parent component is created
- The ImageCarousel component is created, and assigned to `carousel` (via ViewChild)
- We can't access `carousel` until `ngAfterViewInit()` (it will be null)
- We assign the configuration, which sets `style_groupBG = 'red'`
- This in turn sets `background: red` on the host ImageCarousel component
- This component is 'owned' by your parent component, so when it checks for changes it finds a change on `carousel.style.background` and isn't clever enough to know that this isn't a problem so it throws the exception.

One solution is to introduce another wrapper div insider ImageCarousel and set the background color on that, but then you don't get some of the benefits of using `HostBinding` (such as allowing the parent to control the full bounds of the object).

The better solution, in the parent component is to add detectChanges() after setting the config.

```
ngAfterViewInit()
{
    this.carousel.carouselConfig = { ... };
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

This may look quite obvious set out like this, and very similar to other answers but there's a subtle difference.

Consider the case where you don't add `@HostBinding` until later during development. Suddenly you get this error and it doesn't seem to make any sense.

Answer (score 10):

If you are seeing `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` when triggering an `EventEmitter` within `ngAfterViewInit()` then you can pass `true` when creating the `EventEmitter` to make it emit asynchronously after the current change detection cycle.

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  // Emit asynchronously to avoid ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<number>(true);

  ...

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    ...
    this.valueChange.emit(newValue);
    ...
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's my thoughts on what is happening. I have not read the documentation but am sure this is part of why the error is shown.

```
*ngIf="isProcessing()"
```

When using *ngIf, it physically changes the DOM by adding or removing the element every time the condition changes. So if the condition changes before it is rendered to the view (which is highly possible in Angular's world), the error is thrown. See explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375532/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-explained/43375600#43375600) between development and production modes.

```
[hidden]="isProcessing()"
```

When using `[hidden]` it does not physically change the `DOM` but merely hiding the `element` from the view, most likely using `CSS` in the back. The element is still there in the DOM but not visible depending on the condition's value. That is why the error will not occur when using `[hidden]`.

Comment: If `isProcessing()` is doing the ame thing, you must use `!isProcessing()` for the `[hidden]`

Comment: `hidden` doesn't "use CSS in the back", it's a regular HTML property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden

Answer (score 6):

#### Debugging tips

This error can be quite confusing, and it's easy to make a wrong assumption about exactly when it's occuring. I find it helpful to add a lot of debugging statements like this throughout the affected components in the appropriate places. This helps understand the flow.

In the parent put statements like this (the exact string 'EXPRESSIONCHANGED' is important), but other than that these are just examples:

```
    console.log('EXPRESSIONCHANGED - HomePageComponent: constructor');
    console.log('EXPRESSIONCHANGED - HomePageComponent: setting config', newConfig);
    console.log('EXPRESSIONCHANGED - HomePageComponent: setting config ok');
    console.log('EXPRESSIONCHANGED - HomePageComponent: running detectchanges');
```

In the child / services / timer callbacks:

```
    console.log('EXPRESSIONCHANGED - ChildComponent: setting config');
    console.log('EXPRESSIONCHANGED - ChildComponent: setting config ok');
```

If you run `detectChanges` manually add logging for that too:

```
    console.log('EXPRESSIONCHANGED - ChildComponent: running detectchanges');
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

Then in Chrome debugger just filter by 'EXPRESSIONCHANGES'. This will show you exactly the flow and order of everything that gets set, and also exactly at what point Angular throws the error.

[image]

You can also click on the gray links to put breakpoints in.

Another thing to watch out if you have similarly named properties throughout your application (such as `style.background`) make sure you're debugging the one you think you - by setting it to an obscure color value.

Answer (score 5):

My issue was manifest when I added `*ngIf` but that wasn't the cause.  The error was caused by changing the model in `{{}}` tags then trying to display the changed model in the `*ngIf` statement later on.  Here's an example:

```
<div>{{changeMyModelValue()}}</div> <!--don't do this!  or you could get error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError-->
....
<div *ngIf="true">{{myModel.value}}</div>
```

To fix the issue, I changed where I called `changeMyModelValue()` to a place that made more sense.

In my situation I wanted `changeMyModelValue()` called whenever a child component changed the data.  This required I create and emit an event in the child component so the parent could handle it (by calling `changeMyModelValue()`. see https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Answer (score 5):

#### Add `static: true` to the `@ViewChild` decorator

```
@ViewChild(UploadComponent, { static: true }) uploadViewChild: UploadComponent;
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution that worked for me using rxjs

```js
import { startWith, tap, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Data field used to populate on the html
dataSource: any;

....

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.yourAsyncData.
      .pipe(
          startWith(null),
          delay(0),
          tap((res) => this.dataSource = res)
      ).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: what was the problematic code? what is the solution here?

Comment: Hi @mkb the issue was `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.` Happens when value changes are triggered when the DOM changes

Comment: Hi, I mean what did you do here to overcome the problem. You didn't use rxjs at all before or added delay(), or added startWith()? I already use rxjs with various rxjs methods but still get the error, I hope to solve the mistery :(

Comment: The added `delay` make the error go away. It's works similarly to `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 3):

I had this sort of error in Ionic3 (which uses Angular 4 as part of it's technology stack).

For me it was doing this:

`<ion-icon [name]="getFavIconName()"></ion-icon>`

So I was trying to conditionally change the type of an [ion-icon](https://ionicframework.com/docs/ionicons/) from a `pin` to a `remove-circle`, per a mode a screen was operating on.

I'm guessing I'll have to add an `*ngIf` instead.

Answer (score 2):

For my issue, I was reading [github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15464) - "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when changing a component 'non model' value in afterViewInit" and decided to add the ngModel

```
<input type="hidden" ngModel #clientName />
```

It fixed my issue, I hope it helps someone.

Comment: Where on that site does it say to add `ngModel`. And could you please elaborate why this should be helpful?

Comment: When I was tracking down this issue, it led me to investigate the link. After reading the article I added the attribute and it fixed my issue. It is helpful if someone runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had an async property in `LoadingService` with a BehavioralSubject `isLoading`

Using the **[hidden]** model works, but ***ngIf** fails

```
    <h1 [hidden]="!(loaderService.isLoading | async)">
        THIS WORKS FINE
        (Loading Data)
    </h1>

    <h1 *ngIf="!(loaderService.isLoading | async)">
        THIS THROWS ERROR
        (Loading Data)
    </h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue with between RxJS/Observables and static mock data. At first, my application used static mock data, arrays of data in my case

The html was like this:

```
*ngFor="let x of myArray?.splice(0, 10)"
```

So the idea was only display up to 10 elements from `myArray`. `splice()` takes a copy of the original array. To my knowledge *this is perfectly fine in Angular*.

**Then** I changed the data flow to Observable pattern as my 'real' data is coming from [Akita](https://datorama.github.io/akita/) (a state management library). This means my html became:

```
*ngFor="let x of (myArray$ | async)?.splice(0, 10)"
```

where myArray$ is [was] type of `Observable<MyData[]>`, and this data manipulation in the template is what caused the error to happen. Don't do it like this with RxJS objects.

Answer (score 2):

How does `setTimeout?`  or `delay(0)` fix this problem?

Here is why the code above fixes the issue:

The initial value of the flag is `false`, and so the loading indicator will NOT be displayed initially

`ngAfterViewInit()` gets called, but the data source is not immediately called, so no modifications of the loading indicator will be made synchronously via `ngAfterViewInit()`

Angular then finishes rendering the view and reflects the latest data changes on the screen, and the Javascript VM turn completes

One moment later, the `setTimeout()` call (also used inside `delay(0)`) is triggered, and only then the data source loads its data

the loading flag is set to `true`, and the loading indicator will now be displayed

Angular finishes rendering the view, and reflects the latest changes on the screen, which causes the loading indicator to get displayed

No error occurs this time around, and so this fixes the error message.

source: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone coming here:
We make service calls in `ngOnInit` in the following manner and use a variable `displayMain` to control the Mounting of the elements to the DOM.

component.ts

```
  displayMain: boolean;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.displayMain = false;
    // Service Calls go here
    // Service Call 1
    // Service Call 2
    // ...
    this.displayMain = true;
  }
```

---

and component.html

```
<div *ngIf="displayMain"> <!-- This is the Root Element -->
 <!-- All the HTML Goes here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because i was using a variable in component.html which was not declared in component.ts. Once I removed the part in HTML, this error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error because i was dispatching redux actions in modal and modal was not opened at that time. I was dispatching actions the moment modal component recieve input. So i put setTimeout there in order to make sure that modal is opened and then actions are dipatched.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was I was opening up a Ngbmodal popup on load this the object that was being changed after it was checked. I was able to resolve it by opening the modal popup inside of setTimeout.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.modalReference = this.modalService.open(this.modal, { size: "lg" });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when a value changes more than once in the same change detection cycle. I had this problem with a TypeScript getter whose return value was changing very frequently. To fix this, you can restrict a value so that it can only change once per change detection cycle as follows:

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'

private changeDetectionUuid: string
private prevChangeDetectionUuid: string
private value: Date

get frequentlyChangingValue(): any {
  if (this.changeDetectionUuid !== this.prevChangeDetectionUuid) {
    this.prevChangeDetectionUuid = this.changeDetectionUuid
    this.value = new Date()
  }
  return this.value
}

ngAfterContentChecked() {
  this.changeDetectionUuid = uuid()
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>{{ frequentlyChangingValue }}</div>
```

The basic approach here is that each change detection cycle has its own uuid. When the uuid changes, you know that you are on the next cycle. If the cycle has changed then update the value and return it else just return the same value as previously returned on this cycle.

This ensures that each cycle returns only one value. This works fine for frequently updating values given that change detection cycles occur so frequently.

To generate the uuid I've used the uuid npm module but you can use any method that generates a unique random uuid.

Answer (score 0):

The solution...services and rxjs...event emitters and property binding both use rxjs..you are better of implementing it your self, more control, easier to debug.  Remember that event emitters are using rxjs.  Simply, create a service and within an observable,  have each component subscribe to tha observer and either pass new value or cosume value as needed

Comment: Not only this doesn't answer the question, it's also terrible advice. Guys, please don't reimplement rxjs yourself just because you're getting Angular's CD errors. :)

Answer (score 0):

The ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error is a runtime error that can occur when doing angular development. It indicates that a change to the component's template has been detected after the component's view has been checked, which can lead to unexpected behavior.

This error typically occurs when the component's view is being checked, and a change is made to the component's template or data bindings that causes the view to be rechecked. If you want to know what happens behind the scenes...
It's not a bug, it's a feature 
The error is completely reverse-engineered in this article

https://blog.simplified.courses/angular-expression-changed-after-it-has-been-checked-error/