# Angular Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, runtime-error

I have a little problem with Angular 4.
The error below is thrown

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '225px'. Current value: '-21150px'.

Here's my html:

```html
<div class="channelRow" *ngFor="let epgChannel of channelGroupEpg?.epgChannels">
    <div class="epgChannelList">
      {{epgChannel.channel.name}}
    </div>
    <template ngFor let-epgDate [ngForOf]="epgChannel.dates">
        <div class="epgEntry" 
          *ngFor="let epgProgram of epgDate.programs" 
          [style.width]="getWidth(epgProgram, epgDate.date)" 
          (click)="selectProgram(epgProgram)" 
          data-toggle="modal" 
          data-target="#detailModal">
            {{epgProgram.title}}
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```

And this is where the error comes from:

```js
getWidth(program: EPGProgram, date: Date) {
  let min = this.helperService.getDurationByProgramInMinutes(program);
  let startDate = new Date(program.start.getFullYear(), program.start.getMonth(), program.start.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
  let stopDate = new Date(program.stop.getFullYear(), program.stop.getMonth(), program.stop.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
  if (startDate.getTime() !== date.getTime()) {
      let minNextDay = this.helperService.getMinutesToNextDay(program.start, date);
      min = min - minNextDay;
  } 
  if (stopDate.getTime() !== date.getTime()) {
      let minNextDay = this.helperService.getMinutesToLastDay(program.stop, date);
      min = min - minNextDay;
  }
  let width = min * 5;
  return width.toString() + 'px';
}
```

Can someone tell me, why this is the case?

Comment: can you put up a plunker?

Comment: This post could be the solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375532/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-explained

Comment: [Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4) explains this behavior in great details

Answer (score 6):

Component state was changed after it was checked ...

use

```
this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
```

at the end of your method, not forgetting to add

```
private _changeDetectionRef : ChangeDetectorRef
```

as parameter of the constructor of the Component owning your method.

See discution [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005)

Comment: this is after 48 hours of search the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs because you are changing the variable before the angular ouput the HTML.
So, what you can do is. change your variable when the content is loaded.
solution.

```
import { AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

ngAfterContentInit(){
   // write your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix would be to put your code inside a setTimeout().

Answer (score 0):

I had same error outputed. After long research I found out that it's caused when the data that are inputted to html template has changed before angular refresh the html. This error won't be displayed when you switch to production mode. See this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6005) for more information.

Comment: The error won't be displayed in prod mode but that doesn't mean you should ignore it.

Comment: Yes, of couse, but sometimes you can do nothing about it. For example I had problems with translations in html via pipe, i couldn't find way to run another new change detection round. So far it wasn't caused any problem

Comment: @Szarik, _but sometimes you can do nothing about it_ - that's not true, see [this article](https://hackernoon.com/angulars-digest-is-reborn-in-the-newer-version-of-angular-718a961ebd3e#d14a) for more information about the cause

Comment: @Maximus It could do the trick, but in my case I would have to mess up in third-party component which is responsible for translations

Comment: @Szarik, I don't know specifics of your case, I just showed where the cause is explained in detail