# angular 2 - Share Service On Load

Tags: angular

I am trying to share service to a component, for this, I have created service.ts where the code looks like:

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

export class CommonService {
    CommonList = new Subject<any>();
}
```

Of course, this service is in provider list in app.module.ts
Then, I have a component sidebar. 
From sidebar component i am subscribing this service:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.CommonServicePrivate.CommonList.subscribe(
      (result: any) => {
        console.log(result);
      }
    );
  }
```

Here is the problem, If I try to add some list in this service from app.component.ts via some method:

```
  click(){
   this.CommonService.CommonList.next([{"some_key":"some_value"}]);
  }
```

This actually works, but when i try this:

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.CommonService.CommonList.next([{"some_key":"some_value"}]); 
  }
```

it does not work.

The point is that I want to pass this service to a component on load application.

In case of ngAfterViewInit, when i am trying to render this result to some template, i am getting error:
**ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value:**

If someone has this experience could you please share to me.
Thanks.

Comment: i guess you are looking for a router resolve before the component loads you need data in the component right ?

Comment: Yeap, because the information about sidebar is coming from Rest API, and i  need to load it automatically, but another point is that this sidebar i should load in another component as well so i really do not want to call this API twice, solution is that i will store it in service, and from components i will call this service but problem is as i mentioned: via method it works, but onload - it does not work, sometimes gives me error that :

EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest a work around for the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

This is a genuine error as pointed out by gunter here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43375600/2708210

what you can do is make the call inside of a setTimeout i had this issue and this was a work around.

```
 this.subscription = this.service.spinner$
  .subscribe(item => setTimeout(() => this.showProgress = item, 0));
```

> This is a peice of code from my app [git link](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Seems working, but i am little bit wondering about setTimeout, i mean, what will happen if this service takes some time, for example 2 second to get from some api and then load into it? Did you test like this condition?

Comment: Yes i am using it for firebase scenarios and it works fine so farm my case was every time my component loafsbthe values change to and fro so this was the only way + doesn't hamper aot build

Comment: Yeap, i did test as well right now, just made php file with sleep function and called it from angular and it works, man thank you : )

Answer (score 0):

Subject will emit value its subscription when they are subscribe to it. When you're pushing value inside you `CommonList` from `ngOnInit`, it does emit value. But the underlying inner component(event subscription) haven't happened yet.

You could fix this issue just by using `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook, where it ensures that inner Component tree have been initialize(expect content projection). Essentially it will ensure that component `subscription` have been happened.

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.CommonService.CommonList.next([{"some_key":"some_value"}]); 
}
```

---

Or another way of achieving the same goal would be, use `BehaviourSubject` inspite of `Subject`. There difference between these two is `BehaviourSubject` store & emits its last subscription.

Comment: Nope, in this case there is another problem, this should be rendered in template so all the time i am getting error:

ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value:

Comment: @mr_e30 did you give try for this?