# Angular 4: Access to root component

Tags: angular, angular2-template

How can I access to root component for change properties?

**Problem:**

I have difference templates (default and for the custom page), and these templates have the different structure. I want the control to render process via the custom parameter in the class of root component (AppComponent).

As an example:

**app.component.html:**

```
<div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div *ngIf="!customPage">
            <div id="page-wrapper">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div *ngIf="customPage">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
export class AppComponent{
    customPage: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.customPage = false;
    }
}
```

And I try to access from **custom.page.ts:**

```
export class CustomComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
    constructor(private rootComponent: AppComponent) {
    }

    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
        this.rootComponent.customPage = true;
    }
}
```

But I retrieve the error:

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
```

I try to use other lifecycle events, but on all events, I retrieve this error.

And, I think what this solution is not good. Maybe Angular2 have solutions for this problem?

Thank.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 - Share Service On Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45443908/angular-2-share-service-on-load)

Comment: you can use `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf`

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to avoid this error is to wait a tick, for example by using `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout(() => this.rootComponent.customPage = true)
```

Comment: Yes, this works for me. But I think what angular should have the functionality for easy access to any component from runtime context.

Comment: but setTimeout is not a preferred way ever in angular, you can use it as alternate.

Comment: You _do_ have an access to it. The error you're getting is because you're trying to change something during the process of Change Detection, which is what the error says.

Comment: @PardeepJain Not a preferred way, but is sometimes the only way to do something. Indeed, not an ideal code but I'm sure very codebase has larger problems than one or two `setTimeout`s that do a single line of code.