# Angular ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError on custom form control

Tags: angular, recaptcha

My Angular app works fine but after I try to implement ngAfterViewInit on a directive I get the following error:

[image]

Here is the code which I tried to implement:

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.control = this.injector.get(NgControl).control;
    this.setValidator();
  }


  private setValidator() {
    this.control.setValidators(Validators.required);
    this.control.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

The code is based on [this](https://netbasal.com/how-to-integrate-recaptcha-in-your-angular-forms-400c43344d5c) blog post (implements reCAPTCHA with Angular).

I already read a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375532/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-explained) which described the error but I can't fix it in my particular situation.

### Question:

Why am I getting this error and what can I do to fix this?

If you need any additional code or info please comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the function `this.setValidator()` in settimeout

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.control = this.injector.get(NgControl).control;
    setTimeout (()=> {
        this.setValidator();
    },0);
  }
```

For more info on this error read [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: Do read the blog link I posted. It helps to avoid any such scenarios further

Comment: There another way mentioned in the blog to fix it, but I wont recommend it as it runs another detection change cycle after angular's one update cycle ends. That means running extra detection change cycles.