# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError : when Event emitted from Child Component

Tags: angular

[Here is the stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upn18g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), where I am emitting event from child component when the API call is made using the `service.ts` file.

My **child.comp.ts**

```
import { Component, Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import {Service} from './service';

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `Child data: {{data}}`
})
export class ChildComponent  {
  @Output() change = new EventEmitter();
  data: string;
  constructor(private svc: Service){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.change.emit(true);
    this.svc.getMsg()
      .subscribe( data =>{
        this.data = data;
        this.change.emit(false);
      })
  }


}
```

My **app.comp.ts**

```
import { Component ,ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import {Service} from './service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  show= false;
  constructor(svc: Service,private crd: ChangeDetectorRef){}
  showData(event){
    this.show = event;
    // this.crd.detectChanges(); // this stops the error
  }
}
```

As you can see that adding `this.crd.detectChanges();` stops the error by letting `angular` know that this is part which requires another change detection.

But, [I came across this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375532/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-explained#answer-43375600) where this error basically represents **BAD** design. and using `detectChanges()` seems more like a fix as I have to write it explicitly.

Can someone help me with the **GOOD** design where I don't have to write it explicitly `detectChanges()` at the places where the values will change in lifecycles.

Comment: This might [help](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

Comment: why are you emitting an event from ngOnInit? that would cause the error you're seeing.

Comment: @pixelbits Please feel free to update my stackblitz code to correct it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I investigated what should be the best approach to implement what you have written. [I asked the same question to Max](https://medium.com/@maximus.koretskyi/the-general-recommendation-is-to-not-emit-events-from-lifecycle-hooks-ad07924575e3). What I can conclude is that

> Angular follows Unidirectional flow of data, [as you can read over here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/do-you-really-know-what-unidirectional-data-flow-means-in-angular-a6f55cefdc63)

In your case, you are basically changing the value of `show` in the middle of CD. What happens now, is that when CD is triggered 2nd time in DEV mode, it finds out that you **have changed parent data from child component** using `EventEmitter`. This contradicts with the **Unidirectional flow of Angular**. Possible solutions in your case,

1. Use `this.crd.detectChanges()` to let the angular know **explicitly** that you have changed the value , and so the angular will be kind enough to run CD again and won't throw any error
2. OR, implement the `show` behavior in the child itself rather than going against the flow of Parent -> Child.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I had a simular issue. Thanks. After the childcontrol fires the event I use the this.crd.detectChanges();

Answer (score 1):

When you run your app in dev mode (default), the change detector walks through the tree of your components twice:

1. To ensure that you don't have any code in the lifecycle hooks that
   can result in UI changes (I guess, your code violates this by
   emitting event from ngOnInit).
2. Syncronize the UI with the code

So ask yourself if you really need to emit this message from ngOnInit that can cause UI changes elsewhere? If you can't find a better place to do it, try to move the code in the setTimeout() function, which will ensure that this code is invoked on the next event loop cycle, when change detector is done with its pass.