# Get error "Expression has changed after it was checked" disabling an ion-item

Tags: angular, mobile, ionic3

I a have a little form in Ionic 2 and I'm getting the error `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.` when I try to disable the input.

Here is my code:

**.html**

```
<ion-card-content [formGroup]="mfaForm">    
   <ion-input formControlName="otpValue" (keyup)="onOtpChange()" type="number"></ion-input>
</ion-card-content>
```

**.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.buildForm();
}

onOtpChange(): void {
   const otpValue: string = this.mfaForm.get('otpValue').value;
   if (otpValue.length === OTP_CODE_MAX_LENGTH) {
      this.mfaForm.get('otpValue').disable();
   }
}

private buildForm(): void {
   this.mfaForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     otpValue: ['']
   });
}
```

Someone has an idea why it's happening?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43375532/5730444