# onInit function throwing the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError?

Tags: angular

I am learning **Angular**. I am trying to achieve, after the logged in the page redirect to homepage. Following I have tried,

`app.component.html`

```
<header *ngIf='loggedIn'>
<h1>Test portal</h1>
</header>
<login *ngIf='!loggedIn' (homeVar)="loadHome()">Loading..</login>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  loggedIn = 0;
  constructor(private router:Router){}
  ngOnInit(){
    if(!this.loggedIn){
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }

  }
    loadHome():void{
      this.loggedIn=1;
      this.router.navigate(['home']);

  }

}
```

`login.component.ts`

```
export class loginComponent implements OnInit  {
    @Output() homeVar:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

    @SessionStorage() session:any = "";

    ngOnInit(){
        if(this.session != ""){
            this.homeVar.emit(this.session);
        }
    }
   check(){
      this.session = "user";
   }
 }
```

The above code is working fine but it is giving the following error

> ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression
>   has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: 0'. Current
>   value: 'ngIf: 1'.

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code in **login.component.ts**:-

```
ngOnInit(){
  if(this.session != null){

    // add setTimeout
    setTimeout(()=> {
      this.homeVar.emit(this.session);
    }, 0);

  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks it is working. Can you explain what is the reason.? why we have to make the setTimeOut with 0 mili sec?

Comment: @mkHun - This is due to the change detection mechanism which is like a tree structure checking from the top to bottom for changes. But once your `loggedIn` was checked, it was again updated in the same cycle in your other component. Hence, we used `setTimeout` to start a new cycle again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of emitting event inside onInit use constructor

```
export class loginComponent {
    @Output() homeVar:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

    @SessionStorage() session:any = "";

    constructor(){
        if(this.session != ""){
            this.homeVar.emit(this.session);
        }
    }
   check(){
      this.session = "user";
   }
 }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48216423/2742156

Comment: I checked inside the constructor also but it is not emiting the response.

Comment: If it's not emitting then u need to check if(this.session != "")  this statement. My answer is to resolve the error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Answer (score 0):

@mkHun why don't you try to change the variable `loggedIn` to `boolean` this may helps you.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  loggedIn :boolean = false;
  constructor(private router:Router){}
  ngOnInit(){
    if(!this.loggedIn){
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    }

  }
    loadHome():void{
      this.loggedIn = true;
      this.router.navigate(['home']);

  }

}
```

Comment: I have change the code 0 to Boolean but still this is not working

Comment: refer this link which was answered  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375532/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-explained