# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError, when conditionally setting an element attribute

Tags: angular

I am conditionally adding title attributes to elements like so:

```
<div #optionEl class="option-title" [attr.title]="isTitleTruncated(optionEl) ? option.title : null">
    {{option.title}}
</div>
```

which calls:

```
isTitleTruncated(e) {
    return (e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth);
}
```

For cases where the title does get applied, getting:

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'title: null'. Current value: 'title: A very long piece of text'
```

I'm unsure why this is happening, can someone point out why or what could be the possible reasons?

Comment: You can read more about the various reasons causing the same problem, [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375532/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-explained)

Answer (score 1):

This error also occurs when the attribute value changes more than once before rendering/binding initial value/operation to the view attribute.

**For example:**

Lets say you have a flag variable `isTitleTruncated` and initial value is `false`, when view loads it will try to assign value. while doing this binding assignment work, if the flag value gets reassigned to `true or false` again, then  this leads to `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

***Because, What angular does here:***

`Angular runs change detection until the model stabilizes, it might run forever. If Angular doesn't run change detection, then the view might not reflect the current state of the model.`

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm still unclear how I solve the problem though

Comment: You have to check where the variable value gets reassigned and update only once when view renders.