# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression Error On Datepicker Value retrieve

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker

I keep getting this error and I can't seem to find a way to fix this. I using this [angular 4 datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-datepicker) in my project and in this error occurs when it detects change on the dateChanged event.

Here's my full error:

> EditApplicationComponent.html:522 ERROR Error:
>   ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: '[object Object]'. Current
>   value: ''.

Here's my html.

```
<tr *ngFor="let rpr of DocumentMode">

<td style="width: 18%">

<my-date-picker name="from" [options]="DocDatePickerOptions" (dateChanged)="onDocDateChanged($event, rpr)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [placeholder]="placeholder"
            [ngModel]="rpr.SD_VALID_FROM" ></my-date-picker>
</td>
<tr>
```

Here's how I binded and get value to the datepicker. in sample.ts

```
OnInit(){

  this.DocDateRetreive();
}



DocDateRetreive() {
    console.log("came here", this.DocumentMode);
    for (var i = 0; i < this.DocumentMode.length; i++) {
      if (this.DocumentMode[i].SD_VALID_FROM == null) {
        // this.validFrom[i] = new Date();
      }
      else {
        console.log("from:", this.DocumentMode[i].SD_VALID_FROM);

        var validFromTemp = [new Date(this.DocumentMode[i].SD_VALID_FROM)];

        for (var j = 0; j < validFromTemp.length; j++) {
          console.log("valid from temp:", validFromTemp[j]);
          this.validFrom[i] = { date: { year: validFromTemp[j].getFullYear(), month: validFromTemp[j].getMonth() + 1, day: validFromTemp[j].getDate() } };
        }
        console.log("valid", this.validFrom[i]);
        this.DocumentMode[i].SD_VALID_FROM = this.validFrom[i];
      }
    }
  }


  onDocDateChanged(event: IMyDateModel, rpr) {

      var date = event.formatted;
      rpr.SD_VALID_FROM = date;
      console.log("changed", rpr.SD_VALID_FROM);

  }


readThis(inputValue: any, rpr): void {

      myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
        this.FileString = myReader.result;
        // rpr.SD_VALID_FROM = this.validFrom.formatted;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.DocumentMode.length; i++) {
          if (this.DocumentMode[i].DOC_ATTCHE_PATH == rpr.DOC_ATTCHE_PATH) {

            this.DocumentMode[i].SD_VALID_FROM = rpr.SD_VALID_FROM.formatted;
            this.DocumentMode[i].SD_VALID_UNTIL = rpr.SD_VALID_UNTIL;
            this.DocumentMode[i].IS_CHECK = true;
          }
        }
      }
      myReader.readAsDataURL(file);

  }
```

The Datepicker works fine but when it first loads the DOM the error occurs. How do I resolve this issue. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375532/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-explained ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375532/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-explained)

Comment: Günter Zöchbauer from the link Titian posts above perfectly explains the problem and why it really should be addressed.

At the time of writing, Günter's answer is second in popularity, behind the first by just one vote. No answer was marked as officially accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this `this.DocDateRetreive();` after view init.
 there is an angular lifecycle hook called AfterViewInit. You need to implement the inteface in your component class.

```
export class YourComponent implements AfterViewInit{
constructor(){
/*Whatever*/
}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void{
    this.DocDateRetreive();
    }
}
```

This should solve your problem.

If the incoming data you use is making the problem, then you need to go for
AfterContentInit

```
export class YourComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    constructor(){
    /*Whatever*/
    }

        ngAfterContentInit (): void{
        this.DocDateRetreive();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll check and see.

Comment: Vote  and Accept answer if this got to fix your issue.

Comment: Hi When I put `ngAfterContentInit ()` The date doesn't show in the datepicker. `ngAfterViewInit()` won't work

Comment: Try ngAfterContentInit() and debug to find the issue?

Comment: above error happens when I try ngAfterContentInit()

Comment: do you still call it from ngOnInit?

Comment: No This is how I did;  ngAfterContentInit() {  this.DocDateRetreive(); } same error it didn't change anything.