# Ionic ionChange giving ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I've tried to implement all the recommended methods as suggested

[Everything you need to know about the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4)

[ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375532/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-explained)

However, either it's in combination with Ionic or my own developer skills that are letting me down, I am unable to get this to work without hitting the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error.

I have a list of items that I would like to be able to select independently or allow the user to Select All.

In the .ts file I have two methods:

```
  toggleSelectedUser(user) {
    const index = this.selectedUsers.indexOf(user);
    if (index >= 0) {
      this.selectedUsers.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      this.selectedUsers.push(user);
    }
  }

  toggleSelectAll() {
    if (!this.selectedUsers.length) {
      this.selectedUsers = [...this.template.userData];
    } else {
      this.selectedUsers = [];
    }
  }
```

And in my template I am using

```
  <ion-toggle item-end color="secondary" checked="false" id="checkbox{{idx}}" [checked]="isSelected(user)" (ionChange)="toggleSelectedUser(user)"></ion-toggle>
```

Is selected simply does this:

```
  isSelected(user) {
    return this.selectedUsers.indexOf(user) >= 0;
  }
```

Single toggles are working fine, however when I try to perform `toggleSelectAll()` I get the dreaded `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

Answer (score 0):

This is developing mode error first of all and should not come to the production environment. This error usually comes when the `@Input` data is been changed in the child component, as the change detection cycle runs when any changes are detected in the UI.

This error can be fixed calling `detectChanges()` method inside `AfterContentChecked` lifecycle hook. Or you can also use `setTimeout()` function to make you code **async**.

You can look into this article for detailed understanding.

https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Comment: Hi, I've checked the link as I said in my question, however I am unable to implement it, I just get an infinite loop. Where in my code would I put the `setTimeout` to prevent my infinite loop?

Comment: @Taylorsuk yeah you can check by putting your code inside setTimeout