# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError - Shared Service

Tags: angular

Why do I get the following warning in console ? Everything seems to be working as expected but Angular complains. What would be a solution for this issue ?

StackBlitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/github/ntarunmenon/expression-changed)

I know a possible solution is to communicate event via  parent child communication instead of using service but that is not an option for me since this is an isolation of a problem in a larger code base.

**Error Message**

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngIf: false'. Current value: 'ngIf: true'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:20439)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:20427)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:20529)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:23400)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:23389)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:23993)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23921)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (AppComponent.html:6)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23910)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:23288)
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <h1  *ngIf="mainSectionContent?.buttontext?.length > 0">
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <app-employee></app-employee>
</div>
```

**AppComponent**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'expression-changed';
  mainSectionContent:MainSectionContent;
  contentAnnounce$:Observable<MainSectionContent>;

  constructor(private mainContentService:MaincontentService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contentAnnounce$ = this.mainContentService.contentAnnounce$;
    this.contentAnnounce$.subscribe(mainSectionContent => 
      {
        this.mainSectionContent = mainSectionContent
      }
      );
  }
}
```

**EmployeeComponent**

```
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private mainSectionContentService:MaincontentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.mainSectionContentService.announceContent({
      mainheading:'Employee Manger',
      mainsubheading:'To manage PrivilegeManager Employees',
      sectionheading:'Employee List',
      buttontext:'Create Employee'
    });
  }
}
```

**MaincontentService**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MaincontentService {

  private contentAnnounce = new Subject<MainSectionContent>();
  contentAnnounce$ = this.contentAnnounce.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  announceContent(content:MainSectionContent){
    this.contentAnnounce.next(content);
}  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375532/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-explained. Helpful link https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4

Comment: If you are not dependent on the `buttontext` property. Then a cleaner approach would be to use `<h1  *ngIf="(contentAnnounce$|async)">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The case is that ngOnInit of EmployeeComponent is called after `*ngIf="mainSectionContent?.buttontext?.length > 0"` already checked.

First parent component is checked, then goes child `EmployeeComponent`, that changes value, already used to render parent component in same event loop iteration.

This looks like a hack, but you have to call announceContent after first loop passes. You can try call it just after the first event loop finishes:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.mainSectionContentService.announceContent({
        mainheading:'Employee Manger',
        mainsubheading:'To manage PrivilegeManager Employees',
        sectionheading:'Employee List',
        buttontext:'Create Employee'
        });
      }, 
    0);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I used to face the same problem, but this works in a angular native way, you can use ChangeDetectorRef of angular/core class follow the code below:

```
constructor(private cdf: ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

And add this line after you received the data in controller, in your case:

```
this.mainSectionContent = mainSectionContent
this.cdf.detectChanges();
```

What this does is asks the angular service to recheck the changes on DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this **ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError:** error has been going on for a while now and it seems the only and best hack-around is to use the:

```js
setTimeout(() => {...changes...});

---or---

Promise.resolve(null).then(() => {...changes...});
```

But to archive that you have to implement this on every component or area, you want to make those changes. That could be a real hassle.

So I think the best is to bind class `display: none` on that HtmlElement you want to hide.

---

### app.component.scss | css

```css
.d-none {
  display: none
}
```

### app.component.html

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <h1 [class.d-none]="mainSectionContent?.buttontext?.length > 0">
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <app-employee></app-employee>
</div>
```

### app.component.ts | Anywhere

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.mainSectionContentService.announceContent({
    mainheading:'Employee Manger',
    mainsubheading:'To manage PrivilegeManager Employees',
    sectionheading:'Employee List',
    buttontext:'Create Employee'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move the critical part to a new child component like

**app-component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
  <app-welcome [title]="title"></app-welcome>
  <app-employee></app-employee>
</div>
```

**app-component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'expression-changed';
}
```

**welcome-component.html**

```
<h1  *ngIf="mainSectionContent?.buttontext?.length > 0">
  Welcome to {{ title }}!
</h1>
```

**welcome-component.ts**

```
export class WelcomeComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() title!: string;
  mainSectionContent:MainSectionContent;
  contentAnnounce$:Observable<MainSectionContent>;

  constructor(private mainContentService:MaincontentService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contentAnnounce$ = this.mainContentService.contentAnnounce$;
    this.contentAnnounce$.subscribe(mainSectionContent => 
      {
        this.mainSectionContent = mainSectionContent
      }
      );
  }
}
```

Then the error should disappear.