# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError Updating Validator of Sub-Form from Parent

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I've created a few reactive sub-forms that I've connected to the parent form group using the `FormGroupDirective`, but when I update a sub-forms validators from the parent in `ngAfterViewInit` when the controls have been added, and invoke `updateValueAndValidity` I get this error in the console:

```js
ERROR
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: 
Expression has changed after it was checked. 
Previous value: 'ng-valid: true'. Current value: 'ng-valid: false'.
```

Is it possible to avoid this error? I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sub-form-validations?embed=1&file=src/app/page/page.component.ts) of the issue, and you can see the error appear in the console when the application loads as I set the profile description validator and invoke `updateValueAndValidity` in `ngAfterViewInit` of the `PageComponent`.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43375532/1298824)

Comment: This answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53210068/6850994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run change detection in your hook:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

public ngAfterViewInit() {
  ...
  this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```

Or use onPush change detection:

```
import { ..., ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

This will make sure change detection runs only by comparing references instead of when mutating.

Comment: Thanks that works, but I'm not sure what you mean by mutating?  I know how change detection works, and how OnPush only updates the child if the input bindings change, but don't know what you mean by mutating.