# Trigger animation after page load in angular 8, ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular8

As the question suggests, I am trying to figure out a way to get an element animated after the page has been loaded. I have looked all over the place but there seem to be too many and no way to do this at the same time, I am hoping for some guidance. After the page is loaded in mobile the the logo should slowly animate towards the top-right and also scale down in size, if that makes sense.

I am looking for the Angular equivalent of `$(document).ready(function() {}`

As per suggestions, I have used `ngAfterViewInit()` but I still cannot get anything to work.

Below the `index-section.component.html`

```html
<section class="index-section">
  <div [@logoMoveResize]="load_completed ? 'initial' : 'end'" class="index-logo-wrapper" [class.hideOnLoad]="isTrue">
    <figure>
      <img src="assets/icons/logo_mobile.svg" alt="urbanwheels logo">
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="index-media-wrapper">
    <div class="media-container">
      <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/128014070?autoplay=1&color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Itaque contra est, ac dicitis; Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Videsne quam sit magna dissensio?
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

And the `index-section.component.ts`

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, animate, style, group, query, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index-section',
  templateUrl: './index-section.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index-section.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('logoMoveResize', [
      state('initial', style({
        transform: 'translateX(0%) translateY(0%) scale(1)',
      })),
      state('end', style({
        transform: 'translateX(25%) translateY(-25%) scale(.3)',
      })),
      transition('initial <=> end', [animate('1s')]),
    ])
  ]
})
export class IndexSectionComponent implements OnInit {

  load_completed = true;
  innerWidth: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if ( this.innerWidth < 1000 ) {
     this.load_completed = false;
    }
  }
}
```

This the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: have you tried triggering an animation in ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375532/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-explained) answer has provided me with info I need in regards to the question. As @Kevin LeStarge suggested my work around was:

```js
setTimeout(()=> {
    this.load_completed = true;
}, 0);
```

Or as @Lijo suggests using the `AfterContentChecked` life cycle hook:

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef, AfterContentChecked} from '@angular/core';

  constructor(
  private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
   this.cdref.detectChanges();
   this.load_completed = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

set a variable in component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-some',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeInOut', [
      state('void', style({
        opacity: 0
      })),
      transition('void <=> *', animate(1000)),
    ]),
    trigger('EnterLeave', [
      state('flyIn', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }),
        animate('0.5s 300ms ease-in')
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate('0.3s ease-out', style({ transform: 'translateX(100%)' }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

    load_completed = false;

    ngOnInit(){
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
      load_completed = true;
    }

}
```

And in you component.html

```
<div [@fadeInOut]="load_completed"> some random element you want to animate  </div>
```

As above example you can just animate when you need based on the condtion

Comment: @kontenurban please check the above answer

Comment: Essentially it works and I get the desired result but I am getting at this error in the console: `"ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '@EnterLeave: false'. Current value: '@EnterLeave: true'."`

Comment: Also, it seems it animates regardless of weather `load_completed` is true or false!

Answer (score 1):

use [ngAfterViewInit](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#ngAfterViewInit) hook of angular to apply animation to the element.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for the Angular equivalent of $(document).ready(function() {}

the equivalent is

```js
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
  this.zone.onStable.pipe(
    // don't keep the stream open
    first()
  ).subscribe(() => /* zone is stable, do something */)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Angular Resolve** - Interface that classes can implement to be a data provider. A data provider class can be used with the router to resolve data during navigation. The interface defines a resolve() method that will be invoked when the navigation starts. The router will then wait for the data to be resolved before the route is finally activated.

For more details -
https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: your answer is out of context