# How to solve this ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

I understand why this error is being thrown in dev mode and why.

(for those who don't yet: [ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError Explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375532/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-explained))

What i don't understand is how i should fix it in my scenario.

I have a highchart rendering stacked columns and i'm overlaying the highchart with an absolute positioned label on top of the column. I do not know how tall those stacked columns going to be prior to the rendering as the value of the series is dynamic.
So i'm using the `render` event of highcarts to fetch the height of each point in the series and align the label accordingly.

[image]

Those are the chart options:

```js
  chartOptions: Highcharts.Options = {
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      events: {
        render: (e) => {
          if ((e.target as any).series[0]) {
            this.stackColumnHeight += ((e.target as any).series[0].points[0].shapeArgs.height as number);
            this.stackColumnHeight += ((e.target as any).series[1].points[0].shapeArgs.height as number);
          }
        },
      },
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        borderWidth: 0,
        pointWidth: 60
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    series: [],
    title: null,
    xAxis: {
      visible: false
    },
    yAxis: {
      visible: false
    }
  };
```

I'm adding the data after some API fetch has completed:

```js
 ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.service.getData().subscribe(
      res => {
        // chart series
        const series = [{
          data: [res],
          type: 'column',
          color: '#C2C2C2',
          stack: 'other'
        }, {
          data: [9500],
          type: 'column',
          color: '#868686',
          stack: 'other'
        }, {
          data: [9500],
          type: 'column',
          color: '#F0A619'
        }];

        for (const s of series) {
          this.chartOptions.series.push(s as Highcharts.SeriesOptionsType);
        }

        this.updateChart = true;
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    )
  }
```

And this is how i've bound the position properties to the height being set in the `render` event.

```html
<div style="position: absolute; z-index: 1;left: 262px;"
    [ngStyle]="{'bottom': stackColumnHeight + (somePadding) + 'px' }">
    SOME LABEL<br>
    (depending on the column height)
</div>
<highcharts-chart style="width: 60%; height: 320px; display: block;" [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="chartOptions"
    [(update)]="updateChart" [oneToOne]="true"></highcharts-chart>
```

`stackColumnHeight` is 0 at the beginning and gets it value once the data fetch finishes and the chart re-renders, thus realigning the position of the label. This causes the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

How can i get around this?

Comment: https://indepth.dev/posts/1001/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error a good read with some possible solutions. I might try wrapping the render `stackColumnHeight +=` expressions in a `setTimeout(() => {})` first and see if it helps, then try with ChangeDetector or even run in a ngZone. Issue really is if HighCharts is going to be OK with any of that. Without a StackBlitz its hard to test and know for sure.

Comment: Hello Nathan, i've read about the setTimeout fix and it is indeed swallowing the error. I was hoping there's a cleaner solution as i'm afraid i'll be encountering this issue frequently.

Comment: Yea it's a tough one - the elements you need to measure are provided through a third party library, so configuring template refs and view queries is not an option. As far as I can see you're prevented from taking the correct 'angular' approach to this, so a `setTimeout()` solution isn't the worst thing in the world. Maybe there is a HighCharts config that can help with label or bar placement that doesn't require you to re-render, but that's a long shot. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try out below any examples and you will find fix for your problem

**Example 1**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  template: `{{stackColumnHeight}}`,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ExampleComponent { 
 stackColumnHeight = 0;

 constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {

  somethingMethod();
 }

 somethingMethod(e : any) {
    var height = ((e.target as any).series[0].points[0].shapeArgs.height as number) + ((e.target as any).series[1].points[0].shapeArgs.height as number);
  
    this.stackColumnHeight += height;
    this.cdr.markForCheck();  
 }
}
```

**Example 2**

```
  var height = ((e.target as any).series[0].points[0].shapeArgs.height as number + ((e.target as any).series[1].points[0].shapeArgs.height as number);
           
  setTimeout(() => {
   this.stackColumnHeight += height;
  });
```

**Example 3**

```
  let height = ((e.target as any).series[0].points[0].shapeArgs.height as number) + 
  ((e.target as any).series[1].points[0].shapeArgs.height as number);
  
  this.stackColumnHeight += height;
```

Comment: Example 1 sadly doesn't work, example 2 as already mentioned works but seems kind of hacky and with example 3 i don't see a difference to what is in the question.