# Solving Angular NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dialog component which gets some data in the constructor and then builds a role right system which decides the parts of the component to be shown.

Component:

```
export class MyComponent { 

    editPermission!: RolePermission;
    // ...

    constructor(...) {
        this.editPermission = RolePermission.builder()
            .authorizeRole(RoleEnum.ADMIN)
            .comparing(this.data.role);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<edit-component *ngIf="editPermission.authorized" />
<!-- ... -->
```

When I try to open the dialog, I run into the error

```
NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100
```

I already read a thread which solved the problem by adding a ChangeDetectorRef and

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
}
```

to the component.

That *does* work. But obviously I don't want to be forced to add this to every component where I want to user the role-right-system. Why at all do I run into this error? Is there any other possibility to fix it generally?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the code inside `ngAfterViewInit` so that it runs after the view initializes.

```
export class MyComponent { 

    editPermission!: RolePermission;
    // ...

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.editPermission = RolePermission.builder()
            .authorizeRole(RoleEnum.ADMIN)
            .comparing(this.data.role);
    }
}
```

update html as (null check to avoid undefined error!)

```
<edit-component *ngIf="editPermission && editPermission.authorized" />
```

Comment: Now i get ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authorized')``` which makes sense because the view init depends on the authorized-attribute of the editPermission, doesn't it? Or do I get you wrong? I mean the constructor is the first thing which gets called and even then I get the error...

Comment: @ATW updated my answer!

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't seem like a scalable approach, does it? Why at all do I run into the error when I set the permissions directly in the constructor?

Comment: @ATW Since you are refering the varaible in the view, you are getting all these issues, only after the view initializes change detection stops showing this error, its can be ignored if needed, but better to put it in ngafterviewinit, to have a clean console window

Comment: But why exactly does the error occur? I mean I do not change the variable editPermission multiple times, I only set it one time in the constructor.

Comment: @ATW Refer here [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375532/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-explained)